# sending images from 1 vm to another vm

Tags: virtualbox, file-transfer

I want to send images(jpg, jpeg) from my master node to n child nodes.
I made 2 vms(both ubuntu 14.04) on my virtualbox and connected them to the same internal network using the network adapter. After that how should I proceed ?

Comment: What images? Which guest OSes you run on VMs?

Comment: I need to distribute a bunch of images to different nodes. They are .jpg and .jpeg images. Both VMs run on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: scp should work for simple network copy. You can setup rsync if you need to copy a lot of images.

Comment: I dont want to sync all files of master. I want only a portion of it at each node for data distribution. for eg if master has 100 images, i want 10 images at 10 different nodes.

Comment: rsync can do all this read manual: http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync

Comment: You are unclear. but for instance you can use a http server or ftp server and then use the client on the child.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to do it like that? Using a high speed SAN and NFS/ZFS would let you provision any kind of image processing to any node without having to do it manually like that.

Otherwise, use a bash/perl/python/whocares script with a couple nested loops to iterate over the list of images and copy them where they need to go. Bish bash bosh.